# Converting _bn back into PublicKey with Solana

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

When creating a Solana Transaction I set the feePayer with a public key. When I send this transaction between various endpoints, the feePayer gets converted to something like below:

```
"feePayer": {
        "_bn": {
          "negative": 0,
          "words": [
            37883239,
            7439402,
            52491380,
            11153292,
            7903486,
            65863299,
            41062795,
            11403443,
            13257012,
            320410,
            0
          ],
          "length": 10,
          "red": null
        }
      }
```

My question is, how can I convert this feePayer JSON object back as a PublicKey?

I've tried

`new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(feePayer)` or
`new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(feePayer._bn)`

However both don't seem to work, any ideas how to get this json form back into `PublicKey: BN<....>`?

Comment: The solution by @KRist works as long as "_bn" has a string instead of a JSON object. That can be achieved if you stringify and parse the transaction between endpoints

Comment: Try `const publicKey = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(feePayer.toString())` ?

Answer (score 2):

A `BN` is a [BigNumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bn.js). I had a similar case:

```
"feePayer": {
        "_bn": "xcdcasaldkjalsd...."
}
```

Solution to it:

```
import BN from "bn.js";

const publicKeyFromBn = (feePayer) => {
    const bigNumber = new BN(feePayer._bn, 16)
    const decoded = { _bn: bigNumber };
    return new PublicKey(decoded);
};
```

You should play with `new BN(feePayer._bn, 16)` params to make it work specifically for your case.